# Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 10.10.59.4:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port)

Tags: debugging, ssh, phpstorm, xdebug

I have this message: `Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 10.10.59.4:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(` when run debug in PhpStorm.

I am trying to connect to XDebug via **ssh**.
Of course I have read a lot of information and similar questoins.

Maybe you can help me to configure XDebug. I've been sitting on this for long enough.

from my **php.ini**:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

from **/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini**:

```
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
;xdebug.trigger_value=1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9003 #if you want to change the port you can change
```

If I use such command: `php -r "var_dump(phpversion('xdebug'));"` the answer is: `Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-( string(5) "3.1.2"`

XDebug section:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

__   __   _      _                 
\ \ / /  | |    | |                
 \ V / __| | ___| |__  _   _  __ _ 
  > < / _` |/ _ \ '_ \| | | |/ _` |
 / . \ (_| |  __/ |_) | |_| | (_| |
/_/ \_\__,_|\___|_.__/ \__,_|\__, |
                              __/ |
                             |___/ 

Version => 3.1.2
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

             Enabled Features (through 'xdebug.mode' setting)             
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Helpers => ✘ disabled
Coverage => ✘ disabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

                            Optional Features                            
Compressed File Support => no
Clock Source => clock_gettime

                              Diagnostic Log                              
[Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

                              Step Debugging                              
Debugger is not active

                                   PHP                                   
                           Build Configuration                           
Version (Run Time) => 7.4.30
Version (Compile Time) => 7.4.27
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
                                 Settings                                 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gmp.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-propro.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-raphf.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/25-http.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini


Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.mode => debug => debug
xdebug.start_with_request => yes => yes
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.use_compression => 0 => 0
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.log => no value => no value
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_autostart => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
```

Look at this image:
[CLI Interpreter in PhpStorm picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qBEM.png)

If I can provide you more information - just tell me.

Comment: Please note that it's Xdebug that initiates a TCP connection to PhpStorm and not the other way around. This means that `xdebug.client_host` should be an address the remote server can use to connect to your development machine. Are the server and the PC on the same LAN? If not, it makes sense to use [SSH remote port forwarding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html)

Comment: @EugeneMorozov We definitely manage to configure ssh through an additional program, even if phpstorm contains an interpreter that is located on the server via ssh connection, where is the debugger found? (Look at the picture link in question)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.